# Submit form data to php file but view same results on different page

Tags: javascript, php, forms, smarty

I'm trying to send form data to a php file for processing - but I need to display that *same* information on a *separate* page that loads after the user hits submit.

I'm trying to create a barcode scanning search tool.  A user scans a barcode into a textbox and then submits the data to query the sql server.  I'm using PDO queries, the site is internal and the tool will only be accessible to 4 people - so I'm not worried about SQL injection.  It's not that complicated of a tool but this smarty templates thing is such a pain to work with.

I can't simply put the nested php code on the same page because the site is using this Smarty template engine.

Basically my php processing file gets called in a plugin that gets called on the results.tpl page.

results.php->results.tpl->function.scanplugin->php_processing_file(handler.php)

I'm either getting an unknown error or the submit button does nothing.  I can give more details im just trying to keep this short...

Scan.tpl file below is where users scan and submit the barcode.

Any ideas?

```
{include file='globalheader.tpl'}
<h1>Barcode Scanning Tool</h1>

<script type="text/javascript">
function resultsview() {
window.location = "results.php";
return false;
}
</script>

<div id="help">
<h3>Scan a barcode and hit SUBMIT</h3>

<br /><br />

<form action="handler.php" onsubmit="return resultsview()" method="post">
<input type="number" name="barcode" value="1" />
<input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit" />
</form >

</div>

 {include file='globalfooter.tpl'}
```

Comment: im nost sure what you mean by _"I can't simply put the nested php code on the same page"_ which code do you mean? Are you submitting the form? is the data being received and sent? Also, you are using JS to submit (which its not really submitting, it is just redirecting) . This means that whatever you have in your `action` attribute will be ignored.

Comment: why not follow this flow: `form.tpl -> user scans and hits submits -> php processing -> show results.tpl` ?

Comment: Well the problem is i have to display the results on the .tpl smarty template  page.  However, you can't nest php code in the .tpl file because it's not supported.  I've placed my php processing code in a plugin that gets called from the .tpl file.

Comment: It makes it super complicated but unfortunately that's the only way for me to do it if I want to keep the design of the website intact

Comment: I'll try to play around with the flow of it and transfer the results to a separate page from the processing file

Comment: what do you mean? you can definitely send data to smarty. This is one of the main reasons its used for. Read this: http://www.smarty.net/docsv2/en/api.assign.tpl

Answer (score 1):

I guess, from your code, that post-data nowhere is sending, because the js get the action and only redirect it to results.php without post data. I think you must redirect it from handler.php.
Sorry for my bad English: